# Cross-validation in multi-level model

Tags: cross-validation, multilevel-analysis

Suppose I want to estimate the out-of-sample prediction error of a boosted regression model that has random intercepts and slops. There are $G$ groups and $N$ observations. If I want to estimate the out-of-sample prediction error using $k$-fold cross-validation, how do I set up the data partitioning? Is it more complicated that $k$-fold cross-validation? Note: my use case here is the prediction of the data from a *new group*.

Comment: I think I have seen people doing some sort of CV within CV, where they first take k of G groups out, and with the remaining data take k2 of N data out from each of k groups. But in my projects I simply do a CV on the group level, that's it. So if G is not very large, I do a G-fold CV. Otherwise k fold CV where k<G. I wonder what other people do.

Comment: Was totally going to ask if nested folds were the way to go. I mean, that's what it seems like to me, but only if you are guaranteed to have enough to make k_indiv folds for each individual.

Comment: I think k-folds derived from the group level alone are problematic, because you are not cross-validating the within-individual predictive accuracy.

Comment: yea, but I guess we have a bias-variance trade off here.

Comment: Not if we can come up with the proper partitioning mold that reflects the sampling model

Comment: This paper (Roberts et al 2017) discusses CV stratagies for data with dependence structures (including group based dependence) is worth reading: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ecog.02881 Good overview + discussion