Should out-of-sample validation also be out-of-time for time-series?
Introduction
When training a model a "sample" usually refers to the data used to fit the model, so...
Sample: Data used for training model
Out-of-sample: Data not used for training model
Out-of-time: Data not used for training model that is later than data used to train the model
Sometimes regulation says you must perform "out-of-sample" and "out-of-time" validation of your model. But it is not clear what is ment as "out-of-time" is already "out-of-sample". I think "out-of-sample" could be interpreted as validation on customers that were not part of the training "sample".
Interpretation 1
Here the interpretation is that one makes two independent validation runs:

Validation on "out-of-sample" data that is "in-time"
Validation on "out-of-time" data that is also "out-of-sample"


The big flaw as I see it here is that the "out-of-sample" validation will be "in-time", thus the performance metrics will likely be very inflated. An example would be if the "in-time" period was during covid, then you would get "out-of-sample" validation results indicating that you are doing great on these unseen customers, while in reality the model would perform horribly on the unseen customers in a production environment (which is out-of-time).
Interpretation 2
Here the interpretation is that it makes little sense to do any reporting of numbers from the "in-time" "out-of-sample" data, as the numbers don't really say anything about real world performance. Instead all validation numbers reported to the regulators are out-of-time.

Validation on "out-of-sample" data that is "out-of-time" alone. This is the MOST conservative estimate of real world performance. It is also the best metric for generalizability. Here "out-of-sample" refers to customers, who have not even been in the training sample "in-time".
Validation on ALL "out-of-time" data, as this is the best estimate of performance in the immediate future, as a customer base is usually quite stable in the immediate future (e.g. the next 2-3 years).


With this interpretation that numbers you report are the most conservative, likely reflect real-world performance the best and reflect generalizability (e.g. to unseen customers).
Question
Which interpretation would you use? Do you think both interpretations are equally valid?

In the forecasting community, we usually care about "out of time" only. What do you mean by "out of sample" as opposed to "out of time"?

In a project we did both, but out of + time out of training sample was the most important one in the end

The regulation says: "establish a rigorous statistical process including both out-of-time and out-of-sample performance tests for validating the model"

@StephanKolassa In "interpretation 2" out-of-sample means samples that are out-of-time, and customer-ids never seen by the model. Else I could just make a model that used customer-id as a feature, and it would perform ok out-of-time in the immediate future.

Your question reminds me of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564063/references-on-data-partitioning-cross-validation-train-val-test-set-constructi which I asked a while back -- certainly not a duplicate, but I think someone reading one might be interested in the other as well

Not much to add to the great answer by @stephan-kolassa , but I really like this blog post on validation (& test) sets. Basic message: the way you split should match what in reality is your prediction task (i.e. what is yoru existing data & for what do you predict?). E.g. if you predict for some existing customers + new customers, then strictly splitting by customers for your validation misses out on the bit where you have some past interactions with existing customers, but you still need to make sure to split interactions in time.

@Björn In principle I agree that if your model mainly has to perform on existing customers, then it should be evaluated on just those. This thing is that this model is expected to be running for 20 years like the model it is replacing, which means that over time the customer base will definitely change a LOT, thus to account for this the model is also evaluated on "unseen" customers.

If that's the goal, I guess one reasonable test is to see if you can predict the current data based on a model created with 20-year-old data (+any features calculated from current customers that would be used for predictions). Obviously, hard to do (e.g. changes over time in what data gets collected over time, you wouldn't have had number of times customer used app per day 20y ago...) & uncertain whether what changed in the last 20 years would be what changes in the next 20 years. It might be an argument for a model less based on emprical fitting & more on fundamental considerations (+simple).

The model performance has been evaluated yearly and it has been performant. Because of recent regulating the scope has however changed.

For precisely the reasons you outline, validation and testing data should always respect the time ordering and not "learn from the future", because real world performance (I like to call this "in production") is ultimately what we care about. I would argue that this may not only apply to cases commonly called "forecasting", but also to "classification" tasks with time dimensions: if you build a model for credit scoring or churn prediction, the time dynamics may be so strong that you may be well advised to include the time dimension in your modeling and only use out-of-time test/validation sets.
Now, this is to a degree opinion-based.
However, this is in my opinion the absolute consensus in the forecasting community (less so among classifiers), which I have been involved with for a number of years, so yes, I do believe I know what I am talking about. As an Associate Editor and frequent reviewer at the International Journal of Forecasting, any submission that "learns from the future" will get a major revision at the very least, or a reject usually, because the authors apparently did not understand the very first thing about forecasting. Finally, all serious forecasting resources will be very clear on this point.

Thanks for the clarification. Our model is a classification model, but I would still think that e.g. when doing feature selection and hyper parameter tuning, one would want an out-of-time validation set to ensure that one selects time-robust features and parameters. What do you think about that?

That is exactly what I think makes the most sense, because this way you are more realistic about data and model drift. Of course, that means you are at the mercy of any specific things that happened during your training, testing and validation periods... but I would still say that any other way is essentially lying to yourself.

The reason for the question is that the "expert" consultants that have been hired in strongly recommend doing "out-of-sample" validation "in-time". It is against everything I have learned in my 15 years in data science and statistics. It is nice with a confirmation that this "in-time" validation is a bad and misleading approach. But I guess it is a great way to inflate one's performance metrics!

I wonder if it’s not more efficient to not split on time and to flexibly and nonlinearly model the time effect.  If there is a time trend in the “training” data, not modeling that will lead to lack of validation accuracy in the later “test” data and will lead to inaccurate forecasts.

I think that adding time information is great for classical forecasting, but for our use-case information on whether they are evaluated in December or on a Tuesday will not live up to regulation :)

(1) Even consultants can be wrong, and I am sure they would say the same about people giving advice here on CV, absolutely fair. (2) Of course you will need to tailor your analysis pipeline to your specific situation, data, subsequent use of the model etc. (3) I am not quite sure what regulation you are referring to - is this something official, legal or governmental, or a list of requirements drawn up by someone buying a service?

It is regulation within the financial sector where all features have to be financially explainable, and it would be hard to argue that people will not get a loan because they are applying on a Tuesday :)

Thanks, that does make sense. Unfortunately, once you have a predictor that appears to improve your model (whether this is noise or not), humans are very prone to find "explanations". Perhaps people who apply for a loan on Tuesdays are worse risks, because they are more likely not to be holding down a regular 9-5 job (because people with such jobs are more likely to apply on the weekend)...
